# Colorbox Plugin not allowing clicks on the Parent webpage after loading and running

Tags: html, jquery, colorbox

How do I prevent the colorbox plugin from blocking clicks and keyboard inputs after it loads and runs? I've configured the code part correctly but now i'm running into this problem. I want users to be able to access the webpage while this digital ad billboard shows ads but it doesn't block them from using the website. Thanks. The billboard is running on the site http://infinitechllc.cloud

````
```<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
          function openColorBox(){
            $.colorbox({
              iframe: true,
              width: "300px",
              height: "200px",
              left: "0%", 
              top: "0%",
              href: "//zuphaims.com/afu.php?zoneid=3864474",
             
              onLoad: function() {
                $('#cboxClose').remove();
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $(window).colorbox.close();
                }, 31536030000)
              }
            });
          }
    
          function countDown(){
            seconds--
            $("#seconds").text(seconds);
            if (seconds === 0){
              openColorBox();
              clearInterval(i);
            }
          }
    
          var seconds = 5,
              i = setInterval(countDown, 20000);
          var seconds = setInterval(openColorBox, 10000);
        </script>
        <script>
            $('#ColorBox').off('click');
        </script>```
````